# Polynomials Help Greatly Appreciated!

Tags: polynomials

Hope someone here can give me an anwser since I'm stumped. Been working on this for awhile and gotten no where.

So here it is

Show that $x=0$, $y = \pm 1$ are the only rational solutions to $y^2 = x^4 + 1$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please give your attempts/thoughts on the problem and also pinpoint exactly where you are getting stuck.

Comment: Also use formal English for communication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $y=0$ then $x=\sqrt[4]{-1}$ which is not real and therefore not rational.

When $x=0$ then 
$$ y^2=(0)^4+1 $$
$$ y=\pm \sqrt{1} $$
$$ y=\pm 1 $$
So $x=0$ and $y=\pm 1$ are the only two real and in this case rational solutions. Graphically this represents the two points $(0,1) \text{ and } (0,-1)$ where the plot crosses the y-axis

Comment: @amWhy mixed up my wording. I shall edit it. Sometimes the word *"therefore"* makes me feel too powerful.

Comment: Been  there, done that!  Thanks for responding! :-)

Comment: I wish I could up vote this (not enough rep yet). Take this check mark as a consolation. Thanks a lot!